# How create a string by another one? | Selenium Python

Tags: python, string, selenium

First of all, I would like to apologize for my question and for my English, it's my first time here on the forum and I'm noob in python, I'm still learning.

So, in my code, I imported a module that contains some strings for example:

```
users.py:

user1 = Jeremy
user2 = John
user3 = Alana
user4 = Bella
...
```

and in my code, I would like, with each loop, the string "next_user" change according to each repetition... But for some reason, the code I wrote results in a value, and not in the string itself.

```
            from users import *


            next_user = str("user" + str(start_user_num))
            print("The user is"+str(next_user))
```

> result:
>
> The user is user1

and i want it to be "Jeremy"

Sorry if you guys can't understand, I can try to explain better. o___o'

Comment: I'd suggest using lists to solve this problem, because it will make it easier to get the user name by a number.

Comment: @NickODell Sorry, as i said im newbie on it, can you tell me where can i learn about this list thing? Thanks xD

Comment: Here's something which explains how to use lists: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list It goes into a lot of detail, but most of what you need to know is in the "Create Python Lists" section and the "Access List Elements" section.

Comment: Oh i see it now... but unfortunally i can't change the user file to transform it in a list. It have thousand lines.. :(

Comment: You are importing everything from users.py file, so you can just write:    print("The user is",user1)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AbiSaran I can't because i need the user changes for every loop, do you understand?the "start_user_num" changes +1 for every loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your `users.py` since it is not a python script should be changed to `users.txt`

So the contents of the text file is:

> user1 = Jeremy
> user2 = John
> user3 = Alana
> user4 = Bella
> ...

Then you can read everything within the text file, convert it into an array and call upon elements within the array, here is the code for that:

```
with open('users.txt', 'r') as fp:
data = fp.readlines()

users = []

for element in data:
    element = element.replace('\n', '')
    split = element.split(' = ')
    users.append(split[1])


for i in range(len(users)):
    next_user = str(users[i])
    print(f'The user is {next_user}')
```

Which creates the output when run:

> The user is Jeremy
> The user is John
> The user is Alana

I hope this helps

Comment: I did not realise that you could not transform it into a list, I shall update my code shortly

Comment: This should work now

Comment: Bro, i would love have a friend like you to ask these things! Hahah You helped me a lot. Thanks so much, it works perfectly!